# FileInfo.MoveTo does not update FileInfo.Exists

Tags: c#, file

I am moving some file around but noticed that FileInfo.Exists does not really work. In the example below, after moving the file from "foo" to "bar", both `FileInfo` objects seem to `Exist`. In other runs, I have seen both Exists to be false.

```
using System.IO;//File, FileInfo

        public static void TestMoveTo()
        {
            // create file 1
            string FileName = @"d:\temp\foo.txt";
            File.WriteAllText(FileName, "Test file\n");
            FileInfo FI_Test = new FileInfo(FileName);
            // move to file 2
            string NewFileName = @"d:\temp\bar.txt";
            if (File.Exists(NewFileName))
                File.Delete(NewFileName);
            FileInfo FI_New = new FileInfo(NewFileName);
            FI_Test.MoveTo(FI_New.FullName);
            // test
            bool OldExists = FI_Test.Exists;
            bool NewExists = FI_New.Exists;
            // use File.Exists
            bool OldExists2 = File.Exists(FileName);
            bool NewExists2 = File.Exists(NewFileName);
            return;//debug breakpoint
        }
```

Is there a way to `flush` the file system, or `update` the FileInfo objects?

Using the `File.Exists` method works correctly, no wonder, because it probes the file system after the move.

Does this mean that after a change to the file system, the related `FileInfo` objects are just plain invalid?

Comment: read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396): _When first called, FileInfo calls Refresh and caches information about the file. On subsequent calls, you must call Refresh to get the latest copy of the information._

Comment: @Default Great! Somehow I did not find that call. As you were the first, I would select your answer if you make one.

Comment: Thanks, but that's ok. the given answer is more detailed than I would have made it :)

Comment: @Default Good sport. Because of that detail, he might even have started on his answer before you did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FileInfo.Exists` is an instance property; it is created when your `FileInfo` is instatiated; i.e. when you call `FileInfo FI_New = new FileInfo(NewFileName)`. If `NewFileName` does not exist and you later create it, `FI.Exists` will not change. Think about it; if you call:

```
var noSuchFile = @"c:\this file does not exist";
File.Delete(noSuchFile); // just to be sure...
var fileExists = File.Exists();
var fi = new FileInfo(noSuchFile);
File.Create(noSuchFile);
```

Do you think `fileExists` changes from `False` to `True` at the end of that code? Do you think `fi.Exists` changes?  They don't.

`FileInfo.Refresh()` is a method that updates the instance properties, including `Exists`. Or you could call `new FileInfo()` again.

Comment: Thanks. A property *could* call the File.Exists() method, but apparently this one doesn't.

Comment: OK but how come `bool NewExists =  FI_New.Exists` becomes True in my code example, without calling `Refresh`, but not always?